# Git: delete remote conflict branch

Tags: git, git-branch, git-merge-conflict

I'd like to remove a branch that was created during a conflict on remote:

```
git branch -r

origin/master
origin/master_SPITFIREMKV_Jun-26-221715-2020_Conflict
```

I tried variations of

```
git push origin --delete master_SPITFIREMKV_Jun-26-221715-2020_Conflict
```

But it always returns the following error:

```
error: unable to delete 'master_SPITFIREMKV_Jun-26-221715-2020_Conflict': remote ref does not exist
error: failed to push some refs to '...'
```

Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Do you see `origin/master_SPITFIREMKV_Jun-26-221715-2020_Conflict` when running `git branch -a`? (Not -r)

Comment: yes, pruning the remote tracking did the trick, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The branch you wanted to delete is already deleted on the remote side, but the remote tracking branch still exists.  To fix that, you can run `git fetch --prune origin`, which will remove local tracking branches for the remote that no longer exist upstream.